# Missing module in Sage/python

Tags: python, module, sage

I have this error:

```
Compiling eigenplot.spyx...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/abcdefg/executables/sage-6.5-x86_64-Linux/src/bin/sage-run-cython", line 10, in <module>
eval(compile(s, tmp_filename(), 'exec'))

H = Graph(data=matrix(b), format='weighted_adjacency_matrix')
NameError: name 'Graph' is not defined
```

Does it have to do with the fact that I have the sage .exe in another folder, but I have an alias that points directly to it? I call it via sage eigenplot.spyx.

Graph is a function in sage I've called countless times on other servers. But since this is a local build, I have a feeling it is a misplaced module. Any help guys?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the [Sage tutorial](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/tutorial/programming.html#creating-compiled-code): `spyx` files need explicit import statements, even for modules from the Sage library. So add `from sage.all import Graph, matrix` and similar at the top of the file.

Comment: I've used    from "sage.all import *", many times before for .spyx files. I call maybe 20-30 functions from sage. listing every single routine isn't realistic.

Comment: This looks like a bug. I've reported it at http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/18042. A workaround: run Sage and do `attach('filename')`, or do `sage -c "attach('filename')"`.